# Stack overflow for huge file with many variables in different scopes

Tags: c, visual-studio, stack-overflow

I have a autogenerated file creating structs and doing some calculations with them.
Each struct has its dedicated scope.

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
} Addition_t;


uint8_t StructsOverflow(void)
{
    { // use new scope to declare same variable multiple times
        Addition_t x = {.a = 5, .b=6};
        if (x.a == x.b)
            return 1;
    }
    {
        Addition_t x = {.a = 3, .b=6};
        if (x.a == x.b) 
            return 1;
    }
    {
        Addition_t x = {.a = 3, .b=5};
        if (x.a == x.b) 
            return 1;
    }
    // and so on
    // here other structs are created in the same fashion as above
    return 0;
}
```

For a huge number of Lines (about 100,000 structs), running the .exe stops with a StackOverflow: `Exception thrown at 0x00007FF7F2C8B6C8 in EnergyPredictionMain.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000001815603000).`.

Im using the MSVC 2019 compiler and cppvsdbg for debugging.

Why is there an stackoverflow?  In my understanding the variables are destroyed after the scope, so only the memory of one struct should be used.

Comment: Maybe we need to see the "and so on" code? (e.g.) Is the function _recursive_? As posted, this function can _not_ produce a stack overflow. And, how is this invoked? Are there other functions we need to see that might produce this (e.g. other functions that are recursive)?

Comment: Reasons for so. Huge variables on the stack. Too deep recursion. Too deep function calling . Lots of small elements on stack. Without seeing how your cide works it's hard to say

Comment: Presumably you mean there are another 99998 code blocks in the function after `// and so on`, which is not recursive? Note that the C standard does not mention any stack.

Comment: @WeatherVane is right, in this snipped, the first 2 of the 100,000 structs are shown. The other 99,998 structs are created in the same way.

Comment: What do you have against re-using the same struct, but assigning new values?

Comment: odd. If this really is what your function is doing, seems like it could be optimized away anyway. It's all comparisons known at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why?  Because, in a Debug build (IIRC), MSVC doesn't deallocate local variables when they go out of scope in this way.  In a Release build, it will probably work.

But what's really broken here, IMO, is whatever it is that autogenerates that file.  Would it be practical to change it to generate 100,000 separate sub-functions, each initialising (and then processing) one struct?  Then invoke each of them in turn from an (also auto-generated) 'master' function.

If you can do that, it should provide a robust and future-proof fix.

Comment: Using Relase build doesn't solve the problem. However, your suggested workaround, using sub-functions does work. 
I really cant understand, why it doesn't work in the original way.

Comment: @dnrhead Because MSVC quirk, I guess.  I don't believe that compilers are _obliged_ to do what you want.